# How many close votes does a user get per day?

Tags: discussion

Assumming appropriate reputation points, just wondering how many close 'votes' does a user get per day?

Is there a range based on reputation points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You may cast up to 24 close votes per day. (50 on Stack Overflow.)](https://serverfault.com/privileges/close-questions)

Comment: And getting kind of tired of running out of them at 4 hours into the day too. Still got 1000 questions in the queue to review.

Comment: Yeah, this number seem way too low to me based on the request for help that was given in a previous message.  I'd like to suggest that this limit be substancially raised to about 100.